# how to get data from an array in a json?

Tags: arrays, json, angular, dictionary, object

how can I get the information from this json to paint them in angular 10

```
{
  "countries": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "United States"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "India"
    }
 
  ],
  "states": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "countryId": 1,
      "name": "Alabama"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "countryId": 1,
      "name": "Alaska"
    }
  ]
}
```

for normal jsons I used this one, but that jeson has 2 arrays and it won't let me

```
return this.http.get<Country[]>("./assets/data.json");
```

Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

```
<!-- html -->
<div  *ngFor="let item of countri">
  {{item.id}}
</div>
```

model

```
export interface Country {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

and my subscribe

```
countri: Country[] = [];

  this.countriesService.getCountries().subscribe(
      countri => {
        this.countri = countri;
        console.log(countri);
      },
      err => console.log(err)
       );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `any`.
1st way:

```
return this.http.get<any>("./assets/data.json");
```

2nd way define an proper `interface` for your data.

```
export interface IRequest {
 countries: ICourtry[],
 states: IState[]
}

export interface ICourtry{
 id:number;
 name: string;
}

export interface IState{
 id:number;
 name: string;
 countryId: number;
}

return this.http.get<IRequest>("./assets/data.json");
```

This mentioned error(Error trying to diff '[object Object]') are because you are using this json somewhere in your template but it has no values. Hope it will fix it or provide the template code also.

Answer (score 0):

`Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed` , this error usually comes when you try to iterate through ngFor with an Object instead of an Array.

If you are using ngFor,

list.component.ts

```
data={
  "countries": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "United States"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "India"
    }

  ],
  "states": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "countryId": 1,
      "name": "Alabama"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "countryId": 1,
      "name": "Alaska"
    }
  ]
}
```

list.component.html

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of data.countries">
        {{item.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

or

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of data.states">
           {{item.name}}
  </li>
```

Comment: The data is fetched *asynchronously*, so the above solution will break the template.

Comment: @Tony - You need use async pipe in your template.

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, you are most likely trying to iterate over an object rather than an array. Also, since the data you fetch is *asynchronous* you may make use of the following code to avoid any errors. It makes use of the *async* pipe along with the *safe(?)* operator.

.ts

```
jsonData;

ngOnInit() {
   this.jsonData = this.http.get('./assets/data.json');
}
```

template

```
<div *ngFor="let country of (jsonData | async)?.countries">
    {{ country | json}}
</div>

<div *ngFor="let state of (jsonData | async)?.states">
    {{ state | json}}
</div>
```